# The reason of returning javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to internalize message from SOAP API

Tags: xml, soap, sabre

I'm working with a system that's integrated with Sabre SOAP API. From my perspective it's just sending a properly formatted XML (`Content-Type` header is set to `text/xml`) to an endpoint and in response I get another XML. It works, however occasionally (a fraction of requests we're sending) I get this error:

request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ns4:MessageHeader xmlns:ns4="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ns7="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" xmlns:ns8="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ns4:ConversationId>04f446900386013646690cc47a6a2880</ns4:ConversationId>
      <ns4:From>
        <ns4:PartyId ns4:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</ns4:PartyId>
        <ns4:Role/>
      </ns4:From>
      <ns4:To>
        <ns4:PartyId ns4:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</ns4:PartyId>
        <ns4:Role/>
      </ns4:To>
      <ns4:CPAId>CPAID</ns4:CPAId>
      <ns4:Service ns4:type="OTA"/>
      <ns4:Action>PassengerDetailsRQ</ns4:Action>
    </ns4:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" valueType="String">SECURITY_TOKEN_REMOVED</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <PassengerDetailsRQ HaltOnError="false" version="3.2.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
      <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true">
        <EndTransactionRQ>
          <EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
          <Source ReceivedFrom="APPNAME"/>
        </EndTransactionRQ>
      </PostProcessing>
    </PassengerDetailsRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header/>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <soap-env:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Unable to internalize message</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <StackTrace>javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to internalize message</StackTrace>
      </detail>
    </soap-env:Fault>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

I was looking for a human description of what situation this `javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to internalize message` represents but I didn't find anything helpful.

My assumption is that - request has been rejected in the very first layer, so the business layer **has not** processed it, thus I could resend when I get this error. **Am I right?**

I browsed requests that failed and they're as the rest of the requests we're sending - so I guess it's not because of invalid body.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have incorrect Content-Type. Change to Content-Type: text/xml

Comment: could you provide some code to illustrate your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the request that returns this? The ebXML message is formatted
incorrectly, thus this is what Sabre returns. When invalid values are added in the service this can be returned, you will not be able to override this by re-sending. Something is wrong in the service's request (I would say in the header but I have seen this with the main payload as well).

If you can show me a sample request I may be able to check.

Comment: thanks for the respond. I've added the request payload

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Content-Length was the culprit. I had set it incorrectly, the body was bigger than the length set. It caused sabre to respond with this error.

Answer (score 0):

when the size of the message is too big to handle for example size is greater than 20 MB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).